# Is there a way to tell the azsphere cli to use a specific com port?

Tags: hc-05, azure-sphere

I need to link the azsphere cli to a specific com port on my system.  I'm using a Bluetooth <--> Uart device, a HC-05 to configure wifi connectivity on a Sphere project.  It would be slick to use the azsphere cli over this connection, but I suspect that the tool is finding the com port based on some com port property.

Is there a way to force the azsphere cli to use a specific com port?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

There are two different types of UART on the Azure Sphere MT3620 chip.

1. There are regular UARTs that you can access from your Azure Sphere app.  This [sample app](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sphere-samples/tree/master/Samples/WifiConfigViaBle) shows how to use one these UARTs to receive wifi credentials from a BLE chip - the Nordic nRF52 - which sounds similar to the scenario you’re interested in.
2. There are reserved UARTs that only the Azure Sphere OS can access.  When using the MT3620 dev board, they appear as COM ports on your PC but they are only usable by the azsphere CLI: you can’t program them directly.  So there is no reason to control which COM port is used - the azsphere CLI is the only user, and it auto-detects which port to use.